# Symfony2 functional test redirect

Tags: php, rest, symfony, phpunit

I am working with Symfony2 and the FOSRestBundle and I now try to write a functional test for my rest api. I want to POST a user name and display it, similar to http://npmasters.com/2012/11/25/Symfony2-Rest-FOSRestBundle.html. I.e., my controller returns a `View::createRedirect([...],Codes::HTTP_CREATED)` instance.

Now, my test looks like:

```
[...]
    $client = static::createClient(array('debug'=>true));
    $request = $client->request('POST', '/names', 
                      array(),
                      array(),
                      array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),
                      $expression);

    $response = $client->getResponse();
    \print_r($response);
    $this->assertEquals($response->getStatusCode(), 201);
    $response = $client->followRedirect();
    \print_r($response);
```

When I run it, I get this output:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response Object
(
[...]
                [location] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /names/90
                    )
[...]

There was 1 error:

1) MYNAME\MyBundle\Tests\Controller\RestControllerTest::testAddUser
LogicException: The request was not redirected.
```

Why wasn't it redirected?
Where is my mistake?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a redirect, your backend should generate a `301` (“permanent”) or `302` (“temporary”) HTTP status. A status code of `201` [is not really a redirect](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), even if you set a `Location` header. I think it depends on the client implementation what happens on a `201` + `Location`.